Flutter open sms with pretext and without phonenumber
I have a working function to launch sms using url_launcher
launchsms(BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) async {
    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        String smsuri = 'sms:$phoneNumber?body=${Uri.encodeComponent("Hello there")}';
        String calluri = 'tel://$phoneNumber';
        await launchUrl(Uri.parse(calluri));
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        String smsuri = 'sms:$phoneNumber&body=${Uri.encodeComponent("Hello there")}';
        await launchUrl(Uri.parse(smsuri));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Some error occurred. Please try again!'),
        ),
      );
    }
}

I want to launch pretext sms without phone number, so that user has to select a contact or enter phone number. Is it possible?

For Android:
final String smsUri = 'sms:?body=${Uri.encodeComponent("Hello there")}';

For iOS:
final String smsUri = 'sms:?&body=${Uri.encodeComponent("Hello there")}';

//For iOS, please check this in real device. I have tried this in simulator and user can select phone numbers also, but the selected phone numbers are not showing on message screen only loading.

I tried this and it did not work for me with android.

Any error? What's the behavior?

I posted below, but without a phone number I cannot get the body text to populate.  As soon as I add any number or even a + then message will populate.  Looking for a work around.

It does work with a number, but when there is no number present it does not work at all, no text.
final String smsUri = 'sms:123?body=${Uri.encodeComponent("Hello there")}';

I have tried both of these without success.
final String smsUri = 'sms:?body=${Uri.encodeComponent("Hello there")}';

and
final String smsUri = 'sms:''?body=${Uri.encodeComponent("Hello there")}';


When I tried the 2nd one. The recents conversation and select contact screen is visible first. then I select a contact the message is already populating in the message text field. Tried this in a samsung device with android 14. Can you tell me about your device's version?

Trying it in the android studio sim, using Pixel 7 Pro API 35.

Here's my working example: https://imgur.com/a/KitvQ8D
In same device android studio , using Pixel 7 Pro API 35. I also suggest you to test this in real device

Oh wow, maybe the text is just hidden per your sample, didn't see it at first.  Will try again.  Any way to make the focus the text box so the body text can be seen immediately?

Hm. I think it's not possible because the message text box is not in our control.
